# How to calibrate the Sony SmartEyeglass sensors?

Tags: sony-smarteyeglass

reading https://developer.sony.com/reference/seg-sdk/com/sonyericsson/extras/liveware/aef/sensor/Sensor.SensorAccuracy I found out, that a sensor could provide unreliable information and should therefore be calibrated. How can that be done?

Furthermore in the Sony SmartEyeglass Sensors Guide nothing is said about calibration. Is calibration never needed when I follow the steps described under https://developer.sony.com/develop/wearables/smarteyeglass-sdk/guides/sensor-data/ ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is calibrated the same way with phones and other devices with sensors.

You need to hold the SmartEyeglass and move it in air in 8 figure.

Video showing calibration process for sensors in general:
http://www.s3sensor.com/en/s3/calibration/recalibrate/index.html

More technical explanation on necessity of calibration is explained here:
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/17587/what-is-reason-for-electronic-compass-calibration